# ошибка в OpenServer

Tags: php

```
define('PATH_LOG', 'path.log');
include 'inc/log.inc.php';


//log.inc.php
$dt = time();

$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$ref = pathinfo($ref, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

$path = "$dt|$page|$ref\n";

file_put_contents('./log/'.PATH_LOG, $path, FILE_APPEND);

//view-log.inc.php
if(file_exists('log/'.PATH_LOG)){

    $log = file('log/'.PATH_LOG);
    if(is_array($log)){
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($log as $line){
            list($dt, $page, $ref) = explode('|', $line);
            $dt = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $dt);
            echo <<<LINE
            <li>
            $dt: $ref --> $page 
            </li>
            LINE
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
}
```

получаю ошибку:

> Warning: file_put_contents(log/path.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\mysite.local2\inc\log.inc.php on line 8

не могу понять почему?

Comment: Ну исходя из ошибки, то не видно файла или директории. Можно попробовать изменить на `('./log/'.PATH_LOG, $path, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: всё равно не даёт. может проблема в openserver?

Comment: можете код в виде текста добавить а не рисунка?

Comment: изменил с рисунка на текст

Comment: У вас не существует директории log. PHP не создает по умолчанию директории при создании файлов.

Comment: а как я создам директорию log?

Comment: mkdir http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: Ну, либо руками, либо через `mkdir()`

Answer (score 1):

Open Server тут вообще не причем.
Вы обращаетесь к переменной `$ref\n`, которая не определена. У вас есть `$ref`, а `$ref\n` нет! Чтобы поставить перенос строки нужно указать `\n` в кавычках и конкатенировать его с остальной строкой.

Вместо:

`$path = "$dt|$page|$ref\n";`

Попробуй так:

`$path = (string)($dt.' | '.$page.' | '.$ref. "\n");`

Это из учебника Игоря Борисова? Могу скинуть готовое решение через цикл `for`.